# Pixate Freestyle table-view-cell:selected pseudo class

Tags: ios7, uitableview, pixate

I have a UITableView with some custom cells containing a view and some labels.
The view must have a different background color when the cell is selected (als some other properties but lat's start with getting the selected pseudo class working).

I am using PixateFreestyle version 2.1.2.

When applying this line of css:

```
table-view.goals table-view-cell:selected content-view { background-color: blue; }
```

The view is always blue even when the cell is not selected.

Do I need to set some other properties to get this pseudo class working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think the `selected` pseudo class can be used in conjunction with children.

If you just want a different background color on selection, though, why not make your `content-view`'s background **transparent**, and just do this:

```
table-view.goals table-view-cell:selected{ 
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

You should see the Pixate-defined background color on selection. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, then i'll just have to handle selected classes manually, I want to change some more stuff, not only the BG ...